# Plot density chart with Age and Sex

Tags: python, seaborn

This is the easiest way I found for a plot for two variables with Seaborn (Age and Sex):

```
M = df[df["Sex"]=="male"]
F = df[df["Sex"]=="female"]

X1 = M["Age"].dropna()
X2 = F["Age"].dropna()
L1=sns.kdeplot(X1, shade=True, label="male", color="orangered", alpha=0.4)
L2=sns.kdeplot(X2, shade=True, label="female",color='royalblue', alpha=0.4)
```

[image]

How can I make this chart with an improved code?

Thanks.

Comment: Please offer data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine to me.
Another way you can do this is using [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).
I used the Seaborn tips dataset, and added age data to it.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df,hue='sex')
g = g.map(sns.kdeplot,'age',shade=True,alpha=0.4)                      
g.add_legend()
```

This results in:
[image]

Comment: Well, my code works, but I know that is not much eficient. Your solution works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shortcode to achieve the same thing

```py
    sns.kdeplot(df["Age"], shade=True, hue=df["Sex"], color="orangered", 
    alpha=0.4)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the 'hue' option to separate sub-classes of attributes like sex. So you can now define the plot in one line:

```py
plot = sns.PairGrid(df["Age"].dropna(), hue="Sex", **kwargs)
plot = plot.map(sns.kdeplot, **kwargs)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'hue'

Comment: sorry you need to use something other than a kde plot for hue, I've updated my answer

Comment: NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined. What is "**kwargs"?